# I want visible and gone on click of image not on complete row . I used holder pattern

Tags: android, android-custom-view

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View clickedView, int position, long arg3) {
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.err.println("rowClickedEvent");
                position = position - 1;
if (clickedRowID != -1 && clickedRowID != position) {

                    View clickedViewToClose = actualListView
                            .getChildAt(clickedRowID + 1);
                    if (clickedViewToClose != null) {
                        RelativeLayout roww = (RelativeLayout) clickedViewToClose
                                .findViewById(R.id.add_row);
                        roww.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else {
                        System.err.println("clickedViewToClose null");
                    }
                }
                if ((clickedRowID != position)) {



                        }
                    });


                    clickedRowID = position;


                } else if (clickedRowID == position) {


                    RelativeLayout roww = (RelativeLayout) clickedView
                            .findViewById(R.id.add_row);
                    roww.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    clickedRowID = -1;
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

}

Comment: Please format your code and make sure it is not jumbled for others to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter in getView() method add `holder.imageView.setOnClickListener()`

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yourview.setVisibility(View.GONE);//do ur code here

            }
        });
```